# Removing last blank line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

There is a para break at the end of my .csv file. I tried to remove the blank line that is at the end of the file using the following command.

```
sed -i '/^$/d' combined.csv
```

But it does not work and a blank line is still there. I can remove the last line using the following command.

```
sed -i '$d' combined.csv
```

But is it possible to check if the last line is really empty before removing it?

**Update:**

I am using the following command to check if each line start with a number.

```
sed -i '1s/^[^0-9]*//' combined.csv
```

This checks only for the first line and not the rest of the lines. How do I make it check all the lines in the file? This might solve my problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try `${/^$/d;}` this will only match an empty line if it is the last line of the file.

Update: for your second question, just remove the 1 before the s, i.e.: `sed -i 's/^[^0-9]*//' combined.csv`

Comment: Thanks, this works! Could you elaborate on the first sed command?

Comment: `${/^$/d;}`: The first `$` means the last line of the file (you can restrict a command to a line number, and $ means last line). The curly braces mean a block, and within the block you delete `/d;` an empty line `/^$`.

Answer (score 14):

Found this ages ago somewhere and saved the snippet. Do not ask me how it works:

```
perl -i -pe "chomp if eof" combined.csv
```

Comment: If there is no empty line at EOF (\n\n) this will also remove the last \n at EOF - which should not be removed in Unix.

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk: Good point, but that's easily fixed: `perl -pe 'chomp if eof && /^$/' combined.csv`

Comment: Also there are lots of situations in unix where you might want to remove the trailing '\n' because you are not planning on writing the text to a file.

Answer (score 2):

> Try ${/^$/d;} this will only match an empty line if it is the last line of the file.

I tried it with **sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2** and got all blank lines deleted not only the empty line if it is the last line of the file.

I found the following Command, that worked for myself that does the Job.

```
sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}'
```

This Command is from a Collection of useful SED-Oneliners:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Comment: `$ {/^$/d;}` should work just fine, with any POSIX-compatible `sed`. Try `sed '$ {/^$/d;}' <<<$'a\n\nb\n'` and you'll see that only the last line is removed.

Comment: Your alternative does something different: it trims _all_ extra trailing newlines, not just the last one, and it also reads the entire file _at once_, which is unnecessary in this case and problematic with large files.

Answer (score 1):

To remove blank lines you can use `grep .` or `sed '/^$/d'`

It will remove any blank line in the file. I hope you file does not have any blank lines in the middle but this will work in your case.

`cat combined.csv | grep .`

or

`cat combined.csv | sed '/^$/d'`

Answer (score 1):

If you **know for sure** that last line is *empty*, then just use: `...| head -n -1 | ...`