# Delete lines using gawk, awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

### Original question

I have a comma delimited .csv file looking like this:

```
header1,header2,header3
value10,value20,value30
value11,value21,value31
,,
,,
,,
```

How do i delete the "empty lines" at the end of the csv? The number of empty line is not always the same but can be any number.

And how to save the modified csv in a new file?

### Question with Thor's edits

I have a comma delimited .csv file looking like this:

```
header1,header2,header3
value10,value20,value30
value11,value21,value31
[empty line]
[empty line]
[empty line]
```

How do i delete the "empty lines" at the end of the csv? The number of empty line is not always the same but can be any number.

And how to save the modified csv in a new file?

Comment: [This sed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453867/1331399) to the question about removing the last line if it is blank, actually removes all blank lines at the end of a file.

Comment: @thor: **You edit destroyed Ivimma‘s question!** Original questions contains two commas and no empty lines.

Comment: @Cyrus: You are right, I missed that part, my bad.  How do we fix it? There are already answers based on the erroneous edit. I'll add the corrected version to the question.

Comment: Yes want to delete these "empty lines" and keep everything else. the "empty lines" is always placed at the end so no "empty lines" in the middle or somewhere else. In the example I only need to save the first three lines

Comment: Again - how do you define an "empty line"? A line that contains nothing, or a line that contains only commas, or a line that contains nothing but space characters or a line that contains nothing but space characters and commas or something else? Your question is confusing as it contains 2 contradictory examples of possible interpretations of the phrase "empty lines" (courtesy of @Thor?).

Comment: @EdMorton: yep, perhaps deleting the question and posting a new one is the way to go

Comment: A Line that contains only commas

Comment: No luck so far :(

Comment: This one did it: grep -v '^,'  Thanks for all the input

Answer (score 1):

<s>It kind of depends on your definition of an *empty line*. If it really is *empty* as in there is nothing but a newline, using awk you could:</s>

```
$ awk '/./' file
```

or `/^$/` ie, if there's anything but just a newline (default `RS` in awk), print it. If you need the outout to another file:

```
$ awk '/./' file > file2
```

If your definition of *empty* can tolerate space in the record along with the newline:

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]+$/' file
```

**Update**: A-ha, the definition of emptiness boiled down to all commas. OP mentions in the comments that *the "empty lines" is always placed at the end* so once we run into first *empty* line (ie. nothing but commas in the record = `^,+` = `!/[^,]/` - sorry about the double negative), exit.

```
$ awk '!/[^,]/{exit}1' file 
header1,header2,header3
value10,value20,value30
value11,value21,value31
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty (but efficient) way of doing it is to find on your keyboard a character that is not in your file, for instance `µ`. Then just type:

```
tr '\n' 'µ' < myfile.csv | sed -e 's/[,µ]*$//' | tr 'µ' '\n' > out.csv
```

*Not tried, but you can adapt this idea to your own need. Maybe you will have to also add the space character (or the tab, etc.) in the bracket expression.*

The idea is to replace the 'end of line' character by a (temporary) `µ` in order to get a (temporary) single line file; then use a very basic regular expression for deleting what you want; and finally restore the 'end of line' characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use below -

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

Explanation :

```
 ^$ : To search line which doesn't contain anything from start(^) to last($)
 d  : To delete that searched line 
 i  : to make the changes permanent so that you don't need to redirect to another file and then rename it again.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question but it sounds like all you need is:

```
grep -v '[^,]' file1 > file2
```